# Which version of Ubuntu should I install on a macbook pro (intel)?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, macbook, mac

I already installed Ubuntu 12.04 in my MacBook Pro, And everything worked alright except for the WiFi (it said something about the firmware) and because I'm new in this I couldn't fix it, So my question is:

What version of Ubuntu works fine (with the wifi working) "out of the box" in MacBooks?

I already tried to install Ubuntu 11.10 but I couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Most times, newer Ubuntu releases have better hardware support then olders. Especially on MAcBook i would always recommend you to install the latest (lts) version.

Are you able to connect your MacBook to Ethernet while installing? This could help you download drivers for your Wifi which might not be included on the cd. As #blade19899 wrote, you should use the amd+mac64 install iso.
It is possible that you do not have to reinstall: Connect you MacBook to the internet with a Ethernet and then type „Additional Drivers“ into the dash. There might be drivers available to install for your Wifi card.

Comment: Also, this is not all unheard of on non-Apple laptops, too.  Install via ethernet, do first boot with ethernet, install wifi drivers from Additional Drivers, then woohoo.

Answer (score 0):

The version you want is... 12.04.  That is the version that has most things working "out of the box" for Macs.  Unfortunately things will be different from one variation of Macbook to the next and no version ever has *everything* actually working for Macs.  11.10 and prior releases are known to have a LOT of stuff broken for MacBooks with the initial installation.  Most, but not all, of the fixes are unnecessary now with 12.04.

It is very important to know the *exact* model of MacBook Pro, e.g. MacBook Pro 8,1.  I would then search the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org) for it.

Answer (score 0):

I run Ubuntu 12.04 on my Macbook Pro 8.1. Everything works out of the box, except wireless. To get that working, I use the following script:

http://pastebin.com/TyPB9sEh

Answer (score 0):

Hope this [link from Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro) will help you

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.